# Giving title to my different dataframes on excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have few dataframes in an excel sheet with 2 rows of spaces between them and now I want to give title or description to those dfs. How is it possible?

Used this function for multiple dfs

```
# funtion
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    row = 2
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes
dfs = [df,df1,df2]

# run function
multiple_dfs(dfs, 'Validation', 'test1.xlsx', 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your description in a `Series` and write it the same way as the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces, comments):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    row = 2
    for dataframe, comment in zip(df_list, comments):
        pd.Series(comment).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets, startrow=row,
                                    startcol=1, index=False, header=False)
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row + 1, startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 2
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20, 29).reshape(3,3))
dfs = [df,df1,df2]
comments = ['first', 'second', 'third']

# run function
multiple_dfs(dfs, 'Validation', 'test1.xlsx', 1, comments)
```

[image]

---

Update as per comment:

```
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, spaces, comments):   
    row = 2
    for dataframe, comment in zip(df_list, comments):
        pd.Series(comment).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets, startrow=row,
                                    startcol=1, index=False, header=False)
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row + 1, startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 2

# list of dataframes and comments
# ...

# run function
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
multiple_dfs(dfs123, 'Validation1', 1, comments123)
multiple_dfs(dfs456, 'Validation2', 1, comments456)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! And I have two files of excel like those and to combine those, I'm reading those files as df1 and df2 then I'm like:                                                     writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sheet1_sheet2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2', index=False)
writer.save()  But do you if I can do something else instead of that?

Comment: Basically, need one excel file like test1.xlsx with df1,df2,df3 in a sheet name called validation1 and df4,df5,df6 in a sheet name called validation2.

Comment: IIUC, you could use an instance of `writer` created outside of `multiple_dfs` and then do `multiple_dfs(df123, 'Validation1', 'test1.xlsx', 1, comments123)` followed by `multiple_dfs(df456, 'Validation2', 'test1.xlsx', 1, comments456)` (i.e. move `writer = ...` and `writer.save()` out of `multiple_dfs`.

Comment: Where should I give writer.save()? Or else can you update in the above code?

Comment: @newbie see update